# MagicValue is not defined in React

Tags: reactjs

First 30 minutes of starting to learn about React and can't compile the first example of the book.

```
<!doctype html>

<title>Hello Kansas City LOL</title>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
    var anElement = {
        $$typeof:  magicValue,
        type:  "p",
        ref: null,
        props: {
            children: "Hello World From KC."
        }
    };

var renderTarget = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDOM.render(anElement, renderTarget);
</script>
```

The error it gives is that "MagicValue is not defined"
But the way I understood from the book, this MagicValue is some sort of known value for React.
So what's going on?

Comment: Not related to the question though, For starting up with react, official react documentation can really get you up to speed quickly  https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html. You get to create an easy to use dev environment and  the materials are arranged in a friendly way for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the typeof should hold [Symbol.for](https://overreacted.io/why-do-react-elements-have-typeof-property/)

**This should work**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Hello Kansas City LOL</title>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  var anElement = {
    $$typeof: Symbol.for("react.element"),
    type: "p",
    ref: null,
    props: {
      children: "Hello World From KC.",
    },
  };

  var renderTarget = document.getElementById("app");
  ReactDOM.render(anElement, renderTarget);
</script>
```

You can also simplify by using [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

**Like this**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Hello Kansas City LOL</title>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  var anElement = React.createElement(
    /* type */ "marquee",
    /* props */ { bgcolor: "#ffa7c4" },
    /* children */ "hi"
  );

  var renderTarget = document.getElementById("app");
  ReactDOM.render(anElement, renderTarget);
</script>
```